# How To Implement In Apps in my Application

Tags: iphone

In iPhone i have created application now i want to put my application on iTune store i have my account on iPhone portal and on iTune now How i can put my application on iTune to implement this funcationality What i want to do.

My Question,

1) To implement inApps i have to code in application? Which specifyed in this link by iPhone developer.com if yes So where i have to make this coding in my application in delegate class or where.

2) About in apps i dont know anything now i have created application what should i don now just let me know.

Please, Help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/) for the iPhone Dev Program homepage.  There is general info on distribution [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/distribute.html), but you'll need to log in to your dev program account to actually access the tools.  If you don't have an account, you'll need to create one and pay the fee.